# Why dates constructed back from the result of their toString() differ from themselves?

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript code:

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date(date1.toString());
console.log(date1 === date2); //false
console.log(date1); //Fri Oct 30 2015 16:55:56 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
console.log(date2); //Fri Oct 30 2015 16:55:56 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
console.log(date1 == date2); //false
console.log(date2 - date1); // -213
```

I would expect `date2` to be similar to `date1`, since `date2` is a `Date` created from the `string` result of `date1`'s `toString()`. Why is this not the case?

Comment: `date1 === date2` will always fail since tehy are different objects. could be some floating point error in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> console.log(date1 == date2); //false
> ```

They're two objects with different identities, even if they would carry the same value. To compare dates for equivalence, cast them to numeric timestamps:

```
date1.getTime() == date2.getTime()
date1.valueOf() == date2.valueOf()
+date1 == +date2
Number(date1) == Number(date2)
```

> ```
> console.log(date2 - date1); // -213
> ```

`toString()` does ignore the millisecond part. Try to stringify with [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) instead. Or just use the integer timestamp for serialisation.

Comment: So, if I convert date1 to string and convert it back to a Date, then it will be either the same, or older, by a maximum amount of 999 milliseconds?

Comment: @LajosArpad: Correct.

Comment: Thank you, Bergi for the answer, this fully explains the experienced behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same problem as this example

```
var a = { name: "Mikey" };
var b = { name: "Mikey" };

a === b //false
```

But you can compare primitives:

```
var a = 1; 
var b = 1;

a === b //true
```